# Exception when convert BeautifulSoup to Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

I have code as below to scrape site and it is no problems, then I want to only use Selenium so I change code to this, then I got errors, I don't know why, does anyone help me?

webdriver.PhantomJS() Errors

```
Exception: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element does not exist in cache"
```

webdriver.Chrome() Error:

```
Exception: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Selenium only code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # or webdriver.PhantomJS()
a = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(findTag + "." + findValue + " a")
img = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(findTag + "#" + findValue + "img")
href = a.get_attribute('href')
src = img.get_attribute("src")
```

Selenium + BeautifulSoup code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # or webdriver.PhantomJS()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

a = soup.find(findTag, class_=findValue).find_all("a")
img = soup.find(findTag, id=findValue).find_all("img")
href = a.get("href")
src = img.get("src")
```

Comment: Your code is not replicable. What is "findTag" or "findValue", what is your URL ?

Comment: Here is url `http://ipcamera-viewer.com/image/?p=199619_20170301_161955_183.jpg`,  findTag is `ul` and findValue is `grid`

Comment: You are trying to find HTML tags in an image file ?

Comment: sorry, above is image url to download that is  in this [http://ipcamera-viewer.com/view_detail/?camera_code=199619&ymdhi=201703011600](http://ipcamera-viewer.com/view_detail/?camera_code=199619&ymdhi=201703011600)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement waits? It would go as follow:

```
# from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # or webdriver.PhantomJS()

# Here check that your image is in the page's document.
wait = driver.WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "YourImgId"))) 

# Now try to find it in the DOM
img = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(findTag + "#" + findValue + "img")
a = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(findTag + "." + findValue + " a")


href = a.get_attribute('href')
src = img.get_attribute("src")
```

Hope this helps :)

About waits: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

#### Edit: not a wait issue

Just navigate to the page with selenium, enter your credential and then use beautifulsoup to scrape the page. It should then be fine :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

ex_path = r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

# Going to the link
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = ex_path)
driver.get("http://ipcamera-viewer.com/view/?camera_code=199619")

# Enter the password
code = driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
code.send_keys("5042")
code.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Now get the soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
element_ = soup.find("ul", id = "grid")

images_links = []
for img in element_.find_all("img"):
    images_links.append(img.get("src"))

print images_links[0:2]
```

Output:

```
>>> [u'http://ipcamera-viewer.com/image/?p=199619_20170301_201334_5668.jpg', u'http://ipcamera-viewer.com/image/?p=199619_20170301_201329_5611.jpg']
```

Comment: See the comment by @Ettore Rizza, what's the url? Which tag are you interested in? Then we might find a way to proceed

Comment: use `199619/5042` for login

Comment: Hey, I have edited the answer so you can use Selenium and Beautiful Soup together :)

Comment: Is it possible to not use soup?

Comment: Well it depends of your goals, as Selenium only allows for "basic" parsing operations. In fact, using Selenium to parse a page tree would be a bit like using a plane as a car :) Thats why combing both BS with Selenium makes more sense, as it allows you to gain in flexibility

Comment: In my case, the performance is the most important, without bs will be better?